# How to obfuscate spring boot war file?

Tags: spring-boot, obfuscation

I have tried ProGuard, YGuard  tools.
These tools are able to obfuscate the code, but at runtime Spring IOC fails. The obfuscation renames all the packages and classes, thus bean injection does not work at runtime. Am using spring boot 1.5.7 and Maven.

Comment: Have you found a non-paying alternative?

Answer (score 2):

[DashO](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/overview) has [support for Spring](https://www.preemptive.com/dasho/pro/userguide/en/getting_started_spring.html) (i.e. the Wizard will automatically identify and configure Spring beans) and we published an article earlier this year about [how to use DashO with a Spring Boot app](https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/1004-obfuscating-jars-created-with-the-spring-boot-framework/107-support-corner) (you have to extract `BOOT-INF/classes` manually, and configure the entry point manually).

You can [download a trial](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/downloads) for free, and have full access to our technical support if you have trouble getting it working.

Full disclosure: I work for the company that makes DashO.